# InDesign bounding box - stroke issue

Tags: adobe-indesign, path, stroke, bounding-box

When I draw a rectangle, the bounding box covers also the stroke, unlike Illustrator that keeps it on the vector path.

How to deal with this problem? See attachment for a better understanding.

[image]

Comment: As in Illustrator, InDesign has three possible stroke alignments: Center, Outside, Inside. Did you try all of them?

Comment: Hey @Danielillo , yes I did. I've also stated in the screenshot that I am not looking for this solution. Thank you.

Comment: @alexgrigoras if you put the content of your question in an image, you cancel the possibility of text searching for future users. While it's useful to see where the problem is graphically, you should add the whole content in text format.

Comment: @Danielillo I have also stated it in words, in a comment below. To be even more explicit here it is: If I snap to the edge of the stroke and I have 2 rectangles, when I swap fill and stroke (shift+x), the rectangles DO NOT touch anymore. Now I have to take it all ober again and snap them together. Of course, when you create 10 rectangles that is very time-consuming. Thank you! Here is the link to the screenshot: https://imgur.com/RVSDwR0

Comment: The question content in a comment doesn't help that much, there's an edit button at the question to add or modify the text.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Based upon @GerardFalla's answer, Adobe may have improved snapping behavior in more recent versions. I'm still using CS6 most of the time, because I dislike subscription software, and I didn't bother launching CC2017/2018 to test specifically for this answer. This answer is based pretty much on CS6 as I see the behavior.</sub>

---

You can alter the stroke alignment in InDesign via the **Stroke Panel**.

[image]

It appears as though you have the stroke set to align to inside. If you need it centered on the path, like Illustrator, simply click the left-most stroke alignment option in the Stroke Panel.

And you can also enable **Smart Guides** to align things a bit better if needed.

[image]

---

Edit After the comment:

My understanding is you need 2 rectangles to essentially use the same stroke, centered on their paths respectively. So when overlapped it appears like 1 stroke.

InDesign uses the "preview bounds" for strokes. As far as I'm aware, there's no option to change that like there is in Illustrator.  So, you have to compensate for the preview of the strokes.

I don't think you *can* do this in "1 step", but...

- Align the strokes to **inside** on both rectangles
- Snap the edges of the bounding boxes
- Change the stroke alignment to **center**

[image]

You *can* alter the stroke alignment on multiple rectangles at the same time without changing other stroke attributes.

Comment: Thank you, @Scott! That doesn't help, I've already said that. If I follow your solution, I have to do double work: first, I need to draw 2 rectangles, get a guide and snap it to the side of the rectangle, then bring the other rectangle. I just want to draw 2 rectangles and snap to the vector path, with the stroke aligned to center, one to the other. I want to do it in one step, not 2 steps with guides. Thank you!

Comment: See updated answer @alexgrigoras There is no "one step" solution I can think of.

Comment: @Scott: No need for a step, whether one or many: your answer was spot-on, but in fact In Design *already* has this condition *well* covered - see my answer below.

Comment: Might depend upon version @GerardFalla  (Center-aligned strokes) while CS6 will snap the bounding box, it snaps it to the stroke previews not to *other* bounding boxes. And smart guides does not see the bounding box edges with center aligned strokes. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYGl7.gif) -- so, as posted in my answer, it does look like Adobe may have improved this a little in more recent versions.

Comment: @Scott - great to know - thanks for responding so fast mate!

Answer (score 1):

This whole discussion is *off-track* - let's get *back to brass tacks*:

You need to draw out, with snapping, multiple rectangles in InDesign which snap *such that the strokes all **perfectly** line up*.

***IT DOES THAT NOW.***

The bounding box at the outer edge of stroke is a ***non***-issue.

**Why?**

Because InDesign *automatically* snaps *also* to the ***inner*** *stroke* *boundary* - exactly for this reason - *to align strokes.*

So to directly respond to your specific request: I know of ***no*** way to alter this behaviour - however, it's *not necessary* - cos it already works to accomplish your task as-is, out of the box.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and was looking all over the internet for it. I know it's been a few years since it was asked, but since I came across this issue and the solution, I figured it's best to answer.

The problem lies within the preferences options of Illustrator. Under Preferences >> General, there's a box labeled "Use Preview Bounds" that will take the bounding box to the outside of the stroke instead of exactly on the vector edge. Super annoying, (I find this feature) super useless, but I believe this is the answer you're looking for.

Answer Source:
https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/bounding-boxes-and-strokes/td-p/10833829

Comment: Welcome Gibby! You may have overlooked it but this question is about **InDesign**, not Illustrator.